# .browser file target browser matching order

Tags: asp.net-2.0, cross-browser

I need to make my website compatible with Chrome. I have TextBox control adapter, that matches all browser (refID='default'), unfortunately it breaks pages in chrome. The simplest solution would be to keep using the old adapter for all browsers except chrome. My .browser file looks like this:

```
<browsers>
      <browser id="Chrome" parentID="Safari1Plus">
        <identification>
          <userAgent match=".+Chrome/(?'version'(?'major'\d+)\.(?'minor'\d+\.\d+).\d+)" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
          <capability name="browser" value="Chrome" />
          <capability name="majorversion" value="${major}" />
          <capability name="minorversion" value="${minor}" />
          <capability name="version" value="${version}" />
        </capabilities>
        <controlAdapters >
          <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox" adapterType="ChromeTextBoxControlAdapter" />
        </controlAdapters>
      </browser>

      <browser refID="Default">
        <controlAdapters>
          <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox" adapterType="TextBoxControlAdapter" />
        </controlAdapters>
      </browser>
    </browsers>
```

For testing purpouses I set TextBoxControlAdapter to render only 'DEFAULT' text, and ChromeTextBoxControlAdapter to render only 'CHROME' text.

- Currently all browsers print DEFAULT in place of textboxes.
- If I comment out adapter tag in default browser section, chrome shows CHROME and other browsers render regular ASP.NET textbox.
- In no way I can get Chrome render CHROME and all other browsers DEFAULT.

Is it at all possible to configure adaptive rendering this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am also running into this issue, and based on my preliminary investigation, I believe "browser refID" nodes do not inherit settings like "browser ID/parentID" nodes do.

It seems like .NET only applies the information from the first *refID* node it matches and then ignores the rest.  The match order is from the root (i.e. ID="Default") to the more specific (e.g. ID="IE8").

There is a related bug on *connect.microsoft.com* which supports this theory. [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/101991/redefinition-of-capability-added-to-default-browser-definition-does-not-work-in-rtm-version-of-asp-net-2-0?wa=wsignin1.0#details)

My suggestion would be to only apply your custom settings to *refID* nodes that don't have any ancestors.

Unfortunately this means you'll have to duplicate more configuration and also handle default values in code.